# Como preencher um scrollview com grids iguais dinamicamente?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8-1, grid

Galera, eu estou tentando preencher um grid dividido em linhas dentro de um scrollview(para permitir que o usuário visualize todo o conteúdo) com outros grids. 
Cada grid fica dentro de uma linha e contém o conteúdo de uma programação que eu quero mostrar. Eu quero que apareça a lista de programação de um programa de rádio. O grid que mostra cada programação deve ser igual e contém uma imagem e 3 textblocks. EU usei um grid porque queria dividir ele em colunas.

O problema é que eu tenho vários, afinal é uma lista de programação. Mas eu queria alguma biblioteca que me ajude a fazer várias cópias dos grids para preencher com a programação que e o app baixa do servidor. Se eu não fizer isso meu código ficará gigante e feio.

Meu XAML está assim:

```
<ScrollViewer 
                        Grid.Row="2" 
                        Grid.RowSpan="5" 
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
                        <Grid Name="grid_scroll_programacao_santa_ines" Grid.Row="2">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="90"/>

                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid Name="grid_programacao_santa_ines"
                          Grid.Row="0">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Name="txtblock1"
                                   Text="06:00" 
                                   Foreground="#1A1F49"
                                   FontSize="25" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <Image Name="image"
                               Source="/Imagens/SmallLogo.png" 
                               Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <TextBlock Name="txtBlock2"
                                   Text="Acorde e Recorde"
                                   Foreground="#1A1F49"
                                   FontSize="25"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Grid.Column="2"/>
                                <TextBlock Name="txtBlock3" 
                                   Text="Nome do Locutor"
                                   Foreground="#9B9B9B"
                                   FontSize="25"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                   Grid.Column="2"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você busca essa lista de um banco e quer construir a tela dinamicamente, você pode construí-la pelo código.

Apenas com um stackpanel criado em sua tela, faça um loop em cada item da lista e crie um Grid (Grid grid = new Grid();), em seguida voce pode definir seus rows e columns, também os filhos (grid.children.add(new TextBlock()))

Exemplo:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel">

</StackPanel>
```

Classe:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //instancia novo grid
        Grid grid = new Grid();

        //Definir as colunas ou linhas do grid
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(100) });
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(100) });

        //instancia nova label
        Label label = new Label()
        {
            Content = "Coluna da esquerda",
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,                
        };

        // Define em qual coluna do grid a label ficara
        Grid.SetColumn(label, 0);

        //instancia nova label
        Label label2 = new Label()
        {
            Content = "Coluna da direita",
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
        };

        // Define em qual coluna do grid a label ficara
        Grid.SetColumn(label, 1);

        //Adiciona os labels ao grid
        grid.Children.Add(label);
        grid.Children.Add(label2);

        //Adiciona grid ao stackpanel criado no xaml
        stackpanel.Children.Add(grid);
    }
```

Você pode criar sua tela do mesmo modo que no XAML, mas com a vantagem de ser mais dinâmico, principalmente em seu caso.

Comment: Demorou, mas veio. Obrigada pela resposta. Espero que ajude alguém.